# Convex functions and its differential properties [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> **Definition 1.** A convex function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined on an open interval $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is *convex* if the
> inequality $$f(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2)\leq
>  \alpha_1f(x_1)+\alpha_2f(x_2)$$ holds for any points $x_1,x_2\in
>  (a,b)$ and any numbers $\alpha_1\geq 0,\ \alpha_2\geq 0$ such that
> $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=1$. If this inequality is strict whenever $x_1\neq
>  x_2$ and $\alpha_1\alpha_2\neq 0$, the function is *strictly convex*
> on $(a,b)$.
>
> Then he proves the following
>
> **Proposition 5.** A necessary and sufficient condition for a function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable on the open interval
> $(a,b)$ to be convex (downward) on that interval is that its
> derivative $f'$ be nondecreasing on $(a,b)$. A strictly increasing
> $f'$ corresponds to a strictly convex function.
>
> **Corollary.** A necessary and sufficient condition for a function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ having a second derivative on the open
> interval $(a,b)$ to be convex (downward) on $(a,b)$ is that
> $f''(x)\geq 0$ on that interval. The condition $f''(x)>0$ on $(a,b)$
> is sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is strictly convex.
>
> **Example 12.** Let us study the convexity of $f(x)=\sin x$.
>
> Since $f''(x)=-\sin x$, we have $f''(x)<0$ on the intervals $\pi\cdot
>  2k<x<\pi(2k+1)$ and $f''(x)>0$ on $\pi(2k-1)<x<\pi\cdot 2k$, where
> $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows from this, for example, that the arc of
> the graph of $\sin x$ on the closed interval $0\leq x \leq
>  \frac{\pi}{2}$ lies above the chord it subtends everywhere except at
> the endpoints; therefore $\sin x>\frac{2}{\pi}x$ for
> $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

This is an excerpt from Zorich's book and I am a bit confused with the following moment: The author defines the convexity on the finite open intervals $(a,b)$. He shows that $f(x)=\sin x$ is strictly concave on $(0,\pi)$. The line which connects $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{2},1)$ has an equation $y=\frac{2}{\pi}x$. Then he somehow includes the endpoints and deduce that $\sin x>\frac{2}{\pi}x$ on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Intuitively this is clear but I am a bit confused with the rigorous proof since he defines it for open intervals then he moves to closed interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

I'd be thankful if someone can show the more detailed and rigorous explanation of that.

Comment: The open interval is only required when considering the differentiability of the function. This restriction isn't required in general for points where the function is not differentiable such as the boundary points.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I did not get your last sentence.

Comment: Some functions are convex but not differentiable everywhere. For example $f(x)=\vert x \vert$ is convex even though it's not differentiable at $0$. $\sin (x)$ won't be differentiable at the points $0$ and $\pi / 2$ but including won't break convexity because the epigraph will still be a convex set. Proposition $5$ would be false if they didn't restrict it to differentiable functions.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, let me ask you question please. I know that $\sin x$ is convex on $(0,\pi/2]$. How to show that it is convex on $[0,\pi/2]$? We just need to show that $\sin (\alpha t)\geq \alpha \sin t$ where $\alpha\in [0,1]$ and $t\in (0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: This follows from the fact that $\sin x \leq x$. To see this geometrically note that the line through $0$ and any point on $\sin x$ with $x \in (0, \pi /2]$ is above the curve $\sin x$ on that region.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I guess you misunderstood me. We know that $\sin x$ is concave on $(0,\pi/2]$. I want to derive that it is also concave on $[0,\pi/2]$. I really want to prove it analytically.

Comment: What definition of $\sin x$ are you using?

Comment: @CyclotomicField, $\sin x$ is the ordinate of the point to which the point $(1,0)$ moves under a rotation of $x$ radians about the origin.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, let me write my question in a more detailed way: The definition of convexity in Zorich's book is given in terms of open interval. He shows that $\sin x$ is concave on $(0,\pi)$. Hence it is concave on $(0,\pi/2]$. Then he claims that $\sin x>\frac{2}{\pi}x$ for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$. Intuitively I know that this is true. But I'd like to see the rigorous proof.

Comment: @ZFR: I think that it's not correct to conclude that $\sin x$ is concave downward on $(0,\pi/2]$ just because it is proven that $\sin $ is concave downward on $(0,\pi)$ and that's because as per definition (in your post), concave downward etc. is defined on open interval. As I mentioned in response to your earlier comment also, currently I don't know much about convexity/concavity of functions, so if there is any other result on convexity/concavity (which is not present in your post) that refutes my opinion mentioned earlier, then it should be fine to consider $\sin $ concave on $(0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @Koro, that is actually reasonable point. Let me read it more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that $\sin x$ is strictly concave downwards on $(0,\pi)$. Now for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$, note that:

$\begin{align}\sin x= &\sin (\frac 2\pi x (\frac \pi 2))\\=&
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin (\frac 1n (1-\frac 2\pi x) + \frac 2\pi x (\frac \pi 2)) \end {align}$

Noting that $\{2x/\pi,1-2x/\pi\}\subset (0,1)$ and by by strictly concave downward nature of $\sin $ on $(0,\pi)$, we have $\sin (\frac 1n (1-\frac 2\pi x) + \frac 2\pi x (\frac \pi 2)\gt (1-\frac 2\pi x) \sin (\frac 1n) + \frac 2\pi x \sin (\frac \pi 2)$

It follows that: $\lim _{n\to \infty} \sin (\frac 1n (1-\frac 2\pi x) + \frac 2\pi x (\frac \pi 2)\ge \lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\frac 2\pi x) \sin (\frac 1n) + \frac 2\pi x \sin (\frac \pi 2)=\frac 2\pi x$

So it follows that $\sin x\ge \frac 2 \pi x$ for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$.

Now it remains to rule out the equality. If $\sin t=\frac 2\pi t$ for some $t\in (0,\pi/2)$, then define $g:[0,\pi/2]\to \mathbb R$ as follows:

$g(x)=\begin{cases} 0; \text{ when }x=0\\ \sin x-\frac 2\pi x; \text{ when } x\in (0,\pi/2)\\0;\text{ when } x=\pi/2\end{cases}$

By LMVT on $g,\exists c_1\in (0,t)\land c_2\in (t,\pi/2)$ such that $g'(c_1)=\cos c_1=\frac 2\pi=g'(c_2)=\cos c_2$, which is a contradiction as $\cos $ is a decreasing function in $(0,\pi/2)$ in strict sense.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it. Actually I was able to show that $\sin x\geq \frac{2x}{\pi}$ but I have some issues to show that it should be strictly inequality. BTW how did you come up with this reasoning using LMVT? That is really nice

Comment: @ZFR: I'm glad I could help. The reasoning followed from trying to solve the equation $\sin t=\frac {2 t } \pi$ on $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Oh I see. Also I guess we can write $g(x)$ on $[0,\pi/2]$ as $\sin x-\frac{2}{\pi}x$, right? It is not necessary to define it separately for $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: @ZFR: Right, that's not required. I did that in order to simplify things. You may use generalized LMVT on $(a,b)$: In appropriate situations, there exists some $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{\lim_{x\to b^- }f(x) -\lim_{x\to a^+ } f(x)}{b-a }$. Now you don't have to define $g$ at all.

Comment: To be honest, I've never seen this version of Mean value theorem. Do you have a link where I can take a look at the proof, please?

Comment: @ZFR: To prove this, define $g$ as I have done in my answer above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123628/discussion-between-zfr-and-koro).

Comment: Hi! How are you doing? :)

Comment: Hi @ZFR: I am good. How are you?

Comment: Thanks! I am good :) I was wondering can you take a look at the link which I attached above please?

Comment: @ZFR: I'm in the middle of something right now but I'll take a look at the question in the link you shared above.

Comment: that would be great! Thanks for attention!

Comment: @ZFR: My pleasure :)